# Maven: Check Argument Before Running Test

Tags: java, maven

I would like maven to run test phase only if a parameter is defined.
For example:

```
mvn test -Dserver=hosname
```

If server was not specified (or empty) - I don't want the test to run (not in mvn test, nor in mvn install).

How do I do that? How do I get the value of the parameter (e.g. "server") inside my code?

Comment: Using a profile which is activated by the above variable which sets `skipTests=true`? But that sounds more like an integration test than a unit test.

Comment: It is integration tests. Can you please provide with an example for using a profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile can do that in maven what u want

for ex:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>server</id>
          <activation>
            <property>
              <name>server</name>
              <value>${hosname}</value>
            </property>
          </activation>
          <build>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                  <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: @Jonathan, have u applied the solution what i posted

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. I run both "mvn install -Dserver=localhost" and "mvn install" and in both cases the tests were run.

Comment: @Jonathan, replace this token ${hosname} with localhost

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using junit:

- If one test: use `Assume` to check the property (see `@BeforeClass` below) and skip the test if the property is null
- If many, create a parent class and make your tests extend it:

.

```
public class RunIfServerProperty {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetup() {
        Assume.assumeNotNull(System.getProperty("server"));
    }
}
```

see also [`Assume` javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html)

Answer (score 0):

The profile can be used like this:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>server</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <!-- do whatever you need to do -->
  </profile>
</profiles>
```